# Dynamic Day of Week Selection

Tags: php, jquery

I am searching for a dynamic day of week select.

So the code would recognise today is August 1st so... would work like so.

So code ( how I would like it to perform )

```
<select id="selectday" name="selectday" tabindex="13">
<option value="">Please select Preferred Day</option>
<option value="">Today Wed 1st Aug</option>
<option value="">Thursday 2nd Aug</option>
<option value="">Friday 3rd Aug</option>
<option value="">Saturday 4th Aug</option>
<option value="">Sunday 5th Aug</option>
</select>
```

Also would like if possible to factor, if current time is => 12.00pm then Today ( becomes unavailable as an option )

Does this make sense ?

Just wondered if anyone has seen anything like this and how to do it ? Prefer jquery but I suppose php would be fine.

I see plenty of date and time pickers specifically Trents https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

But I need something very very simple and lightweight.

Only needs to show either 7 day block or 14 day block. Would prefer if Sunday was not an option , but that isnt a major issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started... ([Tested example](http://ideone.com/CksJy))

```
<select id="selectday" name="selectday" tabindex="13">
<?php
    $IncludeToday = date("G") < 12;
    for($i=($IncludeToday?0:1);$i<=7;$i++) {
        $TargetDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " +{$i} day");
        print "<option value=\"" . date("Y-m-d", $TargetDate) . "\">" . date("l jS F", $TargetDate) . "</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

This takes the current date in the format `Y-m-d` and uses `strtotime()` to parse an offset of `+ n days`. Then, we output an option with the proper display format and a machine-readable `y-m-d` in the value.

Comment: is there an error in this example? Apologies for seeming dense, but I think something is missing. Thankyou by the way

Comment: I had a typo. I've fixed it and added a link to a working example. I've also improved the date format so it should be exactly what you asked for. `Sunday 5th August`.

Comment: sweet thankyou ! Do you know, if it is possible if, time now is past 12 noon, to not display todays date ?

Comment: No worries a very kind guy has added the time functionality ! Chosen bet answer thankyou

Comment: That's really a new question but since the answer's so simple, I'll add it in.